# One liner for If string is not null or empty else

Tags: c#, if-statement, isnullorempty

I usually use something like this for various reasons throughout an application:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strFoo))
{
     FooTextBox.Text = "0";
}
else
{
     FooTextBox.Text = strFoo;
}
```

If I'm going to be using it a lot I will create a method that returns the desired string. For example:

```
public string NonBlankValueOf(string strTestString)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strTestString))
        return "0";
    else
        return strTestString;
}
```

and use it like:

```
FooTextBox.Text = NonBlankValueOf(strFoo);
```

I always wondered if there was something that was part of C# that would do this for me. Something that could be called like:

```
FooTextBox.Text = String.IsNullOrEmpty(strFoo,"0")
```

the second parameter being the returned value if `String.IsNullOrEmpty(strFoo) == true`

If not does anyone have any better approaches they use?

Comment: `FooTextBox.Text = foo.IsNullOrEmpty ? "0" : foo;`

Comment: Use IsNullOrWhiteSpace as it trims the string.

Comment: I would not change your code, except to make `NonBlankValueOf` static. Don't rely on something that C# might provide - the method `NonBlankValueOf` has a specific meaning to your app, and you control that meaning. For example, what if you needed to change "0" to "1" someday?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

There is a null coalescing operator (`??`), but it would not handle empty strings.

If you were only interested in dealing with null strings, you would use it like

```
string output = somePossiblyNullString ?? "0";
```

For your need specifically, there is the conditional operator `bool expr ? true_value : false_value` that you can use to simplify if/else statement blocks that set or return a value.

```
string output = string.IsNullOrEmpty(someString) ? "0" : someString;
```

Comment: +1 for a good example of when to use null coalesc, although the OP may need it to catch empty string in his/her case.

Comment: Is there a way to do this 2nd thing (string output = string.IsNullOrEmpty(someString) ? "0" : someString;), but if 'someString' is an expression, then capture the result of that expression and return it in the end? I haven't found anything on this yet, but find it would be very useful.

Answer (score 17):

You could use the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
return string.IsNullOrEmpty(strTestString) ? "0" : strTestString

FooTextBox.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(strFoo) ? "0" : strFoo;
```

Answer (score 12):

*You can write your own [**Extension**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) method for type String :-*

```
 public static string NonBlankValueOf(this string source)
 {
    return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source)) ? "0" : source;
 }
```

Now you can use it like with any string type

```
FooTextBox.Text = strFoo.NonBlankValueOf();
```

Answer (score 8):

This may help:

```
public string NonBlankValueOf(string strTestString)
{
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(strTestString)? "0": strTestString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but thought I'd add this to help out,

```
#if DOTNET35
bool isTrulyEmpty = String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || s.Trim().Length == 0;
#else
bool isTrulyEmpty = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with pattern matching with the switch expression in C#8/9

```cs
FooTextBox.Text = strFoo switch
{
    { Length: >0 } s => s, // If the length of the string is greater than 0 
    _ => "0" // Anything else
};
```